# Application with log4j using log file of another application with logback on weblogic server

Tags: java, spring, log4j, weblogic, logback

In my weblogic server I have two independent application. App1 is old web application with web services using log4j:

```
# Console logger
log4j.appender.CONSOLE=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.CONSOLE.layout.ConversionPattern=%-4r %-5p %c %x - %m%n
log4j.appender.CONSOLE.Threshold=ERROR
# APP logger 
log4j.appender.APP=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.APP.DatePattern=.yyyy-MM-dd-HH
log4j.appender.APP.File=${logfile.app}
log4j.appender.APP.encoding=UTF-8
log4j.appender.APP.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.APP.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{DATE} %-5p [%t] %-15c : %m%n

log4j.rootLogger=ERROR, CONSOLE

log4j.logger.cz.isvs=INFO, APP
log4j.logger.org.springframework=WARN, APP

${logfile.app} is replaced during build to target/log/app1.log
```

When there is just this application deployed everything is working OK.

Second app2 is spring boot with also web services application using logback:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <springProfile name="default">
        <property name="LOGS_HOME" value="/app/app_logs/app2" />

        <appender name="appfile" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
            <file>${LOGS_HOME}.log</file>
            <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">
                <Pattern>
                    %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n
                </Pattern>
            </encoder>

            <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
                <fileNamePattern>${LOGS_HOME}.log.%d{yyyy-MM-dd-HH}</fileNamePattern>
            </rollingPolicy>
        </appender>

        <root level="error">
            <appender-ref ref="appfile" />
        </root>

        <logger name="cz.isvs" additivity="false">
            <level value="debug" />
            <appender-ref ref="appfile" />
        </logger>


    </springProfile>

</configuration>
```

When I deployed second application to my weblogic server then both application is logging into app2.log. I am really confused why and how can this happened

Answer (score 0):

Recently I was facing a similar issue with spring boot deployed in weblogic 12c. After investigation found that spring boot is using spring boot logger starter which has some dependency jar i.e. sl4fj, logback, jcl-over-sl4j, jul-to-slf4j, log4j-over-slf4j.jar etc.

From [slf4j manual](https://www.slf4j.org/manual.html) found this:

> The implementation of JCL over SLF4J, i.e jcl-over-slf4j.jar, will
>   allow your project to migrate to SLF4J piecemeal, without breaking
>   compatibility with existing software using JCL. Similarly,
>   log4j-over-slf4j.jar and jul-to-slf4j modules will allow you to
>   redirect log4j and respectively java.util.logging calls to SLF4J.

The bridging jars are responsible to redirect log4j logs, java util logs, commons logging logs to logback via slf4j. After excluding the bridging jar dependencies got the expected result.